# Вызов представления каждые 30 минут

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Надо чтобы определенное представление вызывалось раз в 30 мин.

Я пытался, но не вышло.

Что надо сделать, и что я делаю не так?

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return RedirectToAction("method");

    }

public void method()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(funk);
    task1.Start();
}

    public void funk()
    {
        for (; ; )
        {
            Display();

            Thread.Sleep(1800000);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Display()
    {
          JsonActions js = new JsonActions();
          ViewBag.spis = js.Deseraizable();
          return View();

    }

}
```

Comment: А у вас вьюха Display существует? Да и вообще, вы явно делаете что то странное.

Comment: Да, у меня существует представление.Я не оч шарю в тпл и потоках, а надо сделать.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов - Ну, скажем, существует у него "вьюха" Display, и что? Куда, интересно, ActionResult из Display попадает?

Comment: @Andryxa - "представление вызывалось" - попробуйте объяснить, что Вы понимаете под этими словами. В браузере обновлялась/перегружалась страница?

Comment: @Igor.У меня есть данные,которие обновляются в течение дня.Через ViewBag.spis  я передаю эти данные на представление.Мне нужно, чтобы это действие повторялась, то есть страница перезагружалась раз в 30 мин

Comment: @Andryxa  вы совершенно не понимаете веб технологий. Вы должны вызывать метод со стороны клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте на нужную страницу просто js скрипт:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!JS - сила.

Comment: @Andryxa js просто инструмент, как и все языки.